# how to perform value calculation in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a column inside my user table named `pairCount` which has a value of 2 by default, but whenever an action occur, i want the value to be minus by one (1). so i wrote the following code

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once './include/Constants.php';
require_once './include/DatabaseConn.php';
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
require_once './include/User.php';
require_once './include/Level.php';

use \phputil\JSON;

$user = User::getCurrentUser();

$db = new DatabaseConn();
$link = $db->connect();
$sql = "update users set `payee-1` = NULL,  status  = ?,`pairCount` = ? WHERE `payee-1` = ?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $status, $pairCount, $payee1);
$status = PAIR;


//here is were i did the calculation, but it given me error
$pairCount = $pairCount (-1);



$payee1 = ($user->getUserName());
$res = $stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result();
if ($res) {
    echo "<h1>Congrate you have successfully unsubscribe to a pay this person";
    header('Refresh: 3;url=icant3.php');
} else {
    echo 'undone';
}
```

Comment: Why are you using parentheses?  Do you just mean this?: `$pairCount = $pairCount - 1;`

Comment: why you name your columns `payee-1`? that's very bad habit to use accents or `-`

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea for parentheses in your statement, but PHP thinks you're referencing a function. Just use the decrement operator: `$pairCount--;` Or better yet: `$stmt->bind_param('sss', $status, $pairCount--, $payee1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to do that in your SQL query.

```
update users set `payee-1` = NULL,  status = ?, `pairCount` = pairCount - 1 WHERE `payee-1` = ?
```

Then you don't need to do anything with `$pairCount` variable in your PHP code.

Comment: it brings this error Warning: `mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\icant2.php on line 17
undone`

Comment: This error means that you are trying to push too many variables to the query. You need to remove `$pairCount` from the `bind_param('sss', $status, $pairCount, $payee1);`